# What's the best way to modify every document in a large MongoDB collection without overloading memory?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

At the moment I'm running this task:

```
var skip = 0;
var limit = 5;

gulp.task('add coordinates to visits', function(done) {

(function recurse() {

    Visit.find({})
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .populate('zone')

    .exec(function cb(err, visits) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (visits.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        async.each(visits, function iterateEvents(visit, next) {
            if (!visit.zone) {
                return next();
            } else if (!visit.coordinates.lat || !visit.coordinates.lng) {
                visit.coordinates = {
                    lat: visit.zone.geo.coordinates.lat,
                    lng: visit.zone.geo.coordinates.lng
                };
            }
            visit.save(next);

        }, function cb(err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            skip += limit;
            setTimeout(recurse, 1000);
        });

    });

})();

});
```

But I'm sure there must be a more elegant and optimal method than using `skip`, `limit`, `setTimeout. Is there some mongo or mongoose method for running updating tasks?

Comment: Are you saving these documents back to the database? If so, why wouldn't you update directly on the database?

Comment: Yes I am. I accidently left out `visit.save(next);`. Could you explain your comment further. How would I do that?

Comment: You can use [`Model.update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) to query and update on the database directly.

Comment: But I will still need to query the database first to get the `zone` data that I am to add to Visits. So what is the advantage? See how I populate zone, and then add that data directly to Visits.

Comment: I missed that but would there be any zones that would not be updated by the query? Meaning could you run a similar query directly on the Zones collection.

Comment: No zones are updated. I need all visit documents updated to contain corresponding zone coordinates at the time of running the script. Zones will be changing coordinates, so a visit will need to contain coordinates at the time of the visit and not just link to the zone, as it is now.

Comment: I see now. Unfortunately you will need to retrieve the documents as monogo doesn't support joins but most of the various drivers do locally (as you are doing with `populate`). That said this is an intensive operation as what it is doing is retrieving the selected Visits collection and then `populate` is iterating through them to get the matched Zones documents from the database and then you are iterating over them again to perform your operations and to save them. You use something like [async's parallel limit](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallellimittasks-limit-callback).

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to parallelLimit. But isn't the main issue pulling the full collection in one go? This is why I'm using `limit` and `skip`. I'm looking for a better way than to pull millions of documents into one array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments it seems like Mongoose's [`querystream`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream) might be what you are looking for:

```
var stream = Visits.find().populate('zone').stream();

stream.on('data', function processDoc(visit) {
  var self = this;

  if (visit.zone && (!visit.coordinates.lat || !visit.coordinates.lng)) {
    self.pause();

    visit.update({
      coordinates: {
        lat: visit.zone.geo.coordinates.lat,
        lng: visit.zone.geo.coordinates.lng
      }
    }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { console.log(err); };
      self.resume();
    });
  }
});

stream.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('error', err);
});

stream.on('close', function() {
  console.log('closed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. This is what I was looking for. But for some reason I can't get it working when I populate the zone. I get this error: `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "zone"`. I don't have this problem using my old method.. Any idea?

Comment: Hmmmmm...that generally means the model hasn't been registered prior to executing the query. Can you verify the `Zone` model is available prior to calling the function?

Comment: Thank you. You were correct. My model wasn't registered properly.