# Mongoose subquery and append results to mainquery

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been struggling with the questions for a months now still no solution.

Basically I have 2 mongodb database structures.

One is called Users and another is called Items.

One user can have multiple Items.

User structure is simple =

```
Users = [{
    _id: 1,
    name: "Sam",
    email: "sam@gmail.com",
    group: "Rangers"
  },

  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "Michael",
    email: "michael@gmail.com"
    group: "Muse"
  },

  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "John",
    email: "john@gmail.com"
    group: "Merchant"
  },
  .....
]
```

The Items structures are as follows and each item is assigned to a user.

```
Items = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    user_id: 1,
    item_name: "Flying Sword",
    timestamp: ...
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    user_id: 1,
    item_name: "Invisible Cloak",
    timestamp: ...
  },

  {
    _id: 4,
    user_id: 2,
    item_name: "Iron Shield"
  },

  {
    _id: 5,
    user_id: 7,
    item_name: "Splashing Gun",
    timestamp: ...
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to run a mongoose query that queries the user as primary object.

And upon the returning the results of the user object I want to query the all the Items objects with the filtered users and append them as subdocuments to each user objects previously queried.

For example I want to query

```
Users.find({group: "Muse"}, function(err, users){
    I DON"T KNOW WHAT TO WRITE INSIDE
})
```

Basically the results should be:

```
[
  {
    _id: 4,
   name: "Jack",
   email: "jack@gmail.com",
   group: "Muse",
   items: [
     {
       _id: 8
       name: "Magic Wand",
       user_id: 4,
       timestamp: ...
     }
     {
       _id: 12
       name: "Blue Potion",
       user_id: 4,
       timestamp: ...
     },

     {
       _id: 18
       name: "Teleportation Scroll",
       user_id: 4,
       timestamp: ...
     }
   ]
  }
  .....
  More USERS of similar structure



]
```

Each user will return a maximum of three items which are sorted by timestamp.

Thanks in advance, I tried so many times and failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a multiple step question. So lets list out the steps:

1. Get a list of user documents that match a particular group.
2. Get a list of item documents that are assigned to each matched user from step 1.
3. Assign the appropriate item documents to a new property on the corresponding user document.

This can be tackled a few ways. A first pass might be to retrieve all the user documents and then iterating over them in memory retrieving the list of item documents for each user and appending that list to the user document. If your lists are smallish this shouldn't be too much of an issue but as scale comes into play and this becomes a larger list it could become a memory hog.

**NOTE: all of the following code is untested so it might have typos or the like.**

```
Users.find({group: "Muse"}, function(err, users){
  var userIDs;

  if (err) {
    // do error handling
    return;
  }

  userIDs = users.map(function (user) { return user._id; });

  Items.find({user_id: {$in: userIDs}}, function (err, items) {
    if (err) {
      // do error handling
      return;
    }

    users.forEach(function (user) {
      user.items = items.filter(function (item) {
        return item.user_id === user._id;
      });
    });

    // do something with modified users object
  });
});
```

While this will solve the problem there are plenty of improvements that can be made to make it a bit more performant as well as "clean".

For instance, lets use promises since this involves async operations anyway. *Assuming Mongoose is [configured to use the native Promise object](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2688#issuecomment-124553465) or a then/catch compliant library*

```
Users.find({group: "Muse"}).exec().then(function(users) {
  var userIDs = users.map(function(user) {
    return user._id;
  });

  // returns a promise
  return Promise.all([
    // include users for the next `then`
    // avoids having to store it outside the scope of the handlers
    users,
    Items.find({
      user_id: {
        $in: userIDs
      }
    }).exec()
  ]);
}).then(function(results) {
  var users = results[0];
  var items = results[1];

  users.forEach(function(user) {
    user.items = items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.user_id === user._id;
    });
  });

  return users;
}).catch(function (err) {
  // do something with errors from either find
});
```

This makes it subjectively a bit more readable but doesn't really help since we are doing a lot of manipulation in memory. Again, this might not be a concern if the document collections are smallish. However if is, there is a tradeoff that can be made with breaking up the request for items into one-per-user. Thus only working on chunks of the item list at a time.

We will also use [Bluebird's map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) to limit the number of concurrent requests for items.

```
Users.find({group: "Muse"}).exec().then(function(users) {
  return bluebird.map(users, function(user) {
    return Items.find({user_id: user._id}).exec().then(function (items) {
      user.items = items;
      return user;
    });
  }, {concurrency: 5});
}).then(function(users) {
  // do something with users 
}).catch(function(err) {
  // do something with errors from either find
});
```

This limits the amount of in memory manipulation for items but still leaves us iterating over users in memory. That can be tackled as well by using mongoose streams but I will leave that up to you to explore on your own (there are also other questions already on SO on [how to use streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551786/whats-the-best-way-to-modify-every-document-in-a-large-mongodb-collection-witho/29553562#29553562)).

Answer (score 0):

This makes it subjectively a bit more readable but doesn't really help since we are doing a lot of manipulation in memory. Again, this might not be a concern if the document collections are smallish. However if is, there is a tradeoff that can be made with breaking up the request for items into one-per-user. Thus only working on chunks of the item list at a time.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. You'll be able to post comments when you get enough reputation.